# How much time passed since my scheduleOnce() method in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-x, scheduler

I want to know how much time passed since my scheduleOnce() method and in some situation reduce rest time that remain ,how I can do that?

Comment: do you mean past or passed? From or since? You could maybe post some example/pseudo code what you want to achieve.

Comment: oh sorry for misspell. actually I'm trying to make a game and in my game I want to speed up my game, for example speeding up/down of my sprite movement ,for this reason I divide interval of scheduler's to value of gamePlaySpeed but for scheduleOnce() method's that passed at before I dont know how can I do that.

Comment: you would have to avoid using schedule methods and instead run scheduled code using action sequences (wait+callfunc or runblock), then you could simply change the speed property of the sequences